# python flask send data through post and url

Tags: python, api, rest, post, flask

I have a question regarding sending data via a CURL through POST and sending data through the URL. More generally, I have a flask route

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def clone:
   ...
```

How can I also send data using a URL? I want to do something like this:

```
<my-server>:port/create/arg1/arg2/arg3
```

I just figured out you can do something like

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/create/<op>/<source>/<target>', methods=['GET'])    
def clone(op = None, source = None, target = None):
    ...
```

Which will work. Is this a good approach?

Comment: So is the question "How can I send a post using curl to my flask app" or "How can my flask app accept query parameters"? I'm a bit confused as to what you're looking for.

Comment: How can my flask app *also* accept query parameters". I am able to POST data using CURL.

Answer (score 2):

To access the actual query string (everything after the `?`) use:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
    def clone:
        return request.query_string
```

To access known query parameters:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
    def clone:
        user = request.args.get('user')
```

If you're looking to use variables sent like `/arg1/arg2/arg3` use:

```
@app.route('/create/<arg1>/<arg2>/<arg3>', methods=['POST'])
    def clone(arg1, arg2, arg3):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that you are looking for how to POST directly to your flask app, here is a way to make it in python

```
import request
 
dictionary = {"something":"100"}
response   = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/create', json=dictionary)
response.json()
```

you can also change .json() for .content or .text functions.